# Enable Audience Demographics Overview by Age & Gender

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I use Google Analytics for my iOS app and i want to get data about gender and age of my users.

Here is my code inside AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
     let Tracker = GAI.sharedInstance()
    //Add Publisher Track ID
    Tracker.trackerWithTrackingId("UA-XXXXXXXX-2")
    Tracker.trackUncaughtExceptions = true
    Tracker.dispatchInterval = 10
    Tracker.logger.logLevel = GAILogLevel.Verbose
    let defaultTracker = Tracker.defaultTracker
    defaultTracker.allowIDFACollection = true
```

I added AdSupport.framework and libAdIdAccess.a to my project and enabled age and gender tracking in google analytics settings but still i have no gender/age data and google says that gender/age tracking is enabled but my analytics code needs to be updated to track this data.

Maybe i need to use IDFA - I don't know how. What i need to do?

Comment: Hi,  you did everything its  correct. i am also faced same problem and having same doubt, finally i am contact with google analytics team and they replied clearly, i am posted answer below please refer my answer and get idea. it will help  you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the framework or your app has access to the calendar, and/or the primary users date of birth, this won't be possible.

If anything, I'd suggest looking at the Calendar (EventKit) to get this kind of information.

Obtaining it any other way would pretty much breach Apple Developer T's and C's

Comment: I thought that Google has it's own algorithm based on statistic of user actions, so all I need to do is to provide Google analytics with user's unique id.

Comment: Apple are extremely strict (and rightly so) about user security and data privacy. In terms of the GA API, that will get data from stored cookies and other data like that which as it is has been listed as a security risk. The apps run in a sandbox environment, so any attempt to get data from calendars etc... without authorisation will result in the app being either rejected from the app store or your app simply having no access to calendars unless the user approves it.

Comment: sorry, but i am asking about receiving age/gender data from Google - not from user